# Mongo conditional aggregation within set operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I am trying to perform a conditional update of MongoDB record with the following transaction.

```
db.collection(SESSIONS_COLLECTION)
  .updateOne({_id: ObjectId(id)},
    {
      $set: {
        end: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $gt: ["$end", latestActionDate] }, then: "$end", else: latestActionDate
          }
        }
      },
      $push: {
        actions: {
          $each: data.map(action => ({
            ...action,
            time: new Date(action.time)
          }))
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

But all my efforts are crushed with.
`MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$cond' in 'end.$cond' is not valid for storage.`
It is possible that such operations are simply not allowed, but I prefer to think that I'm missing something here.

Comment: It's not working cause you're mixing up normal update operation with aggregation operators, what is your DB version ?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with you're mixing up normal update operation with aggregation operators, to use aggregation operators in update you need to wrap your update part in `[]` to say it's actually an aggregation pipeline.

Starting MongoDB version `4.2` you can [update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) :

**Code :**

```
let actionArray = data.map((action) => ({
  ...action,
  time: new Date(action.time),
}));

db.collection(SESSIONS_COLLECTION).updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) }, [
  {
    $set: {
      end: {
        $cond: [{ $gt: ["$end", latestActionDate] }, "$end", latestActionDate]
      }
    }
  },  
  /** (fail safe stage) this second stage is optional but needed in general as `$push` will add a new array
   *  if that field doesn't exists earlier to update operation 
   * but `$concatArray` doesn't, So this helps to add `[]` prior to below step */
  {
    $set: { actions: { $ifNull: [ "$actions", [] ] } }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      actions: { $concatArrays: ["$actions", actionArray] }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Note :**

As we're using aggregation pipeline here, you need to use aggregation operators and usage of few query/update operators doesn't work.